# c++ read from file skip certain lines

Tags: c++, file, csv

i have text file in this format

```
 wins = 2
 Player
 10,45,23
 90,2,23
```

i have to store the 10 45 23 into a vector and pass it to a function, problem is it breaks after first line

```
    string csvLine;
int userInput;
ifstream  data("CWoutput.txt");
string line;
string str;
vector<string> listOfScores;
while(getline(data,line))
{
    stringstream  lineStream(line);
    string        cell;
    while(getline(lineStream,cell,'\n'))
    {
        if (cell.at(0) != 'w'  || cell.at(0) != 'P')
        { 
            while(getline(lineStream,cell,','))
            {
                cout<<line<<endl;

                listOfScores.push_back(cell);
            }
        }
    }
    vector<transaction> vectorScores= this->winner(listOfCells);
    bool hasWon= false;
    hasWon= this->validateRule2(vectorScores);
    if(hasWon== true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, please replace `if (hasWon== true) { return true; } else { return false; }` with `return hasWon;`.

Comment: yes, or directly `return this->validateRule2(vectorScores)`

Comment: Or `return this->validateRule2(this->winner(listOfCells))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are using `linestaream` in loop? You are getting whole line by calling `getline(data,line)`.

so you can do

```
while(getline(data,line))
{


        if (line.at(0) != 'w'  || line.at(0) != 'P')
        { 
            std::vector<std::string> x = split(line, ',');
            listOfScores.insert(listOfScores.end(),x.begin(),x.end());
        }
}
```

and you can use split functions:

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this statement `while(getline(lineStream,cell,'\n'))`

Your `lineStream` does not contain the `'\n'` character because it is discarded by the previous `getline( data, line)` function.

Your while loop may be simplified to something like:

```
while(getline(data,line))
{
    data.clear();
    if (line[0] != 'w'  && line[0] != 'P') {
      stringstream  lineStream(line);
      string        cell;
      while(getline(lineStream,cell,','))
      {
        cout<<line<<endl;

        listOfScores.push_back(cell);
      }
      vector<transaction> vectorScores= this->winner(listOfCells);
      bool hasWon= false;
      hasWon= this->validateRule2(vectorScores);
      return hasWon;
   }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt event go to the next line